# How to save two overlapped plots together in one single file?

Tags: julia, julia-plots

```
using Plots
plot(0:10,sin);
plot!(0:10,sin,seriestype = :scatter)
```

[image]
In this example, the output are actually two plots. How can I save them in one file?

I searched and tried some method, but they only support one single plot and I haven't found any functions for multiple plots.

Answer (score 3):

This is just one figure - `plot!` (with a bang) mutates the figure object created in the first `plot` call.

Saving this is as simple as `savefig("my_output.svg")` - if this does not work as expected please provide more details.

Not directly related, but seeing that you are overlaying a scatter plot onto a line plot you might be interested in the `linetype` kwarg:

```
plot(0:10, sin, linetype = :scatterpath)
plot(0:10, sin, lt = :scatterpath) # short form alias
```

will both produce a line and scatter at the same time (with a single label and single colour).

Comment: To the same effect, a shorter keyword (and maybe easier to understand) that I use often is `m=:o` (or `m=:circle` for the nitpicker) :)